# Use setTimeout to run function then print message

Tags: javascript

I need some direction with javascript setTimeout.

I need to execute player.stop after 60 seconds then print a message on the page that it has timed out.

The following code executes the player.stop just fine.

The problem is that it displays the "timestatus" message as soon as the page loads instead of after the timer runs out.

Any suggestions?

```
  onPlay:
  function()
  {
    setTimeout(() => player.stop(), 60000);
    document.getElementById("timestatus").innerHTML = timeMsg;
  },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have this written, the only thing that's inside the `setTimeout` callback is the call to `player.stop`.  Your code says this:

- Queue a timeout for one minute later
- Immediately after that, set `innerHTML`

You need to put both statements inside that callback function instead:

```
setTimeout( () => {
    player.stop();
    document.getElementById("timestatus").innerHTML = timeMsg;
}, 60000 );
```

The new code says this:

- Queue a timeout for 1 minute later (and when it is called, do 2 separate operations)

Answer (score 0):

The message need to be inside the `setTimout` callback function

```
onPlay: function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    player.stop()
    document.getElementById("timestatus").innerHTML = timeMsg;
  }, 6000);
}
```